# The effect hooks in React is not re-executed after the dependencies are updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-effect-with-ref-72xwsq?file=%2Fsrc%2FChild.tsx)

Child.tsx

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useState } from 'react'

const Child = forwardRef<any, {}>((_, ref) => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState<any | null>(null)
  const divEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
  const [val, setVal] = useState('')

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      console.log('useImperativeHandle', obj)
      return obj!
    },
    [obj]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (divEl?.current) {
      setObj((e: any) => {
        if (e) return e

        return {
          setValue(v: string) {
            console.log('value', v)
            setVal(v)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }, [divEl.current])

  return (
    <div ref={divEl}>
      {val}
    </div>
  )
})

export default Child
```

Parent.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  const oRef = useRef<any>(null)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect setValue')
    oRef.current?.setValue(String(Date.now()))
  }, [oRef.current])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Child ref={oRef} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>Click Me</button>
        <div>{count}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

main.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import Parent from '@/types/Parent'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(<Parent />)
```

The Child component is blank.
The console output:

```
Child.tsx:11 useImperativeHandle null
Parent.tsx:9 useEffect setValue
Child.tsx:11 useImperativeHandle {setValue: ƒ}
```

When I click the button, the Child component display the real value. The console output:

```
Parent.tsx:9 useEffect setValue
Child.tsx:24 value 1696008660769
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-effect-with-ref-72xwsq?file=%2Fsrc%2FChild.tsx)

The original code contains additional business logic, where the Child component needs to forward a ref to allow the outer component to set its internal value. The provided code is a simplified version, but it still doesn't work. I have tried asking ChatGPT for help, but I haven't received any substantial assistance.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.6.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^4.4.9"
}
```

Comment: Ref updates won't rerender a component: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361703/react-refs-do-not-update-between-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not watch for changes in ref objects. This means that it does not schedule a new render when they change and therefor do not trigger effects.

Use useState instead.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I passed the setObj of the state from the parent component to the child component instead of using a ref, and it indeed worked. Thank you.